# Express passport-ldap nodejs How to pass variable to another middleware

Tags: express, passport.js

Hi please can you Help me,

on app.js I use passport-ldapauth startegy and works!

....

```
var OPTS = {
        server: {
            url: 'ldap://myipldap:389',
            bindDn: 'uid={{username}},O=My Company Group',
            //bindCredentials: '{{req.body.password}}',
            searchBase: 'O=My Company Group',
            searchFilter: 'uid={{username}}'                                                
        }
    };            
        passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));       
        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user);
         });         
         passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user);
         });

        app.post('/login', (req,res,next) => { 

            passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {
                //session: false,
                successRedirect:'/index',
                failureRedirect:'/login',
                failureFlash:true           
            })(req, res, next);
        });
```

.... before executing success redirect I need to query on table mysql and check the user's grant

I think I do that, I have successRedirect to index and I have a export module call accessoSicuro :

```
// accessSicuro It's exported module:
module.exports = {
accessoSicuro:function(req,res,next){    
if(req.isAuthenticated()){    

/*
HERE I WANT to check the mysql table and pass the returned parameter to next () method and then use the value to the middleware index
*/
return next();
}
req.flash('msg_errore','Sorry, no entry, no auth ldap');
res.redirect('/login');
}
}   

app.get('/index',accessoSicuro,(req,res,next)=>{    

// HERE THE RESPONSE VALUE OF mysql response FROM accessoSicuro method

        sess=req.session;
        idUser = sess.passport.user;    
        res.render('index');    
    });
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way you can pass variables via the next() middleware. The best practice (since it is the one mentioned in express documentation) is to use [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals)

Comment: Actually `res.locals` is still passed to `next()` via `res` variable.  And `next` function in middleware allows you pass 1 argument.  In this case, express will seek the first middleware with `(err, req, res, next)` arguments.  And the argument you passed is `err` in this case (i.e. `next(err)`).